# Utilizing multiple, weighed data models for a Mahout recommender

Tags: mahout, recommendation-engine

I have a boolean preference recommender based on user similarity. My data set essentially contains  relations where ItemId are articles the user has decided to read. I'd like to add a second data model containing  where ItemId is a subscription to a particular topic.

The only way I can imagine doing this is by merging the two together, offsetting the subscription IDs so that they don't collide with the article IDs. For weighting I considered dropping the boolean preference setup and introducing preference scores, where the articles subset has a preference score of 1 (for example) and the subscriptions subset has a preference score of 2.

I'm not sure if this would work, however, because the preference score isn't exactly analogous to the sort of weighting I'm after; they probably include some concept of lower scores representing dissatisfaction.

I have to imagine there's a better way to do this or at least that there are tweaks to my plan which would make it work more along the lines I desire.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're thinking of it in the right way. Yes you want a bit more expressiveness than a simple exists/doesn't exist for subscriptions and articles since they mean somewhat different things. I would suggest picking weights that reflect their relative frequency. For example if users have read 100K articles over all time, and made 10000 subscriptions, then you might pick a subscription weight to be "10" and a read weight to be "1".

This doesn't quite work if you treat those values as preference scores, for a number of reasons. It works better if you use an approach that treats them like what they are, which are linear weights.

I would point you to the ALS-WR algorithm, which is specifically designed for this type of input. For example: [Collaborative Filtering for Implicit Feedback Datasets](http://www2.research.att.com/~yifanhu/PUB/cf.pdf)

This is implemented in Mahout as `ParallelALSFactorizationJob` on Hadoop. It works nicely though requires Hadoop. (I can't take credit for that, though I did write most of the recommender code in Mahout.)

Advertisement: I'm working on commercializing a "next generation" system, evolved from my work in Mahout, as [Myrrix](http://myrrix.com/). It is an implementation of ALS-WR and is ideal for your kind of input. It's quite easy to [download and run](http://myrrix.com/quick-start/), and doesn't need Hadoop.

Given that it may be directly suitable for your problem I don't mind plugging it here.

Comment: I don't see multiple dataset support i Myrrix apart from experimental EXAMPLE: MERGING RECOMMENDERS

Comment: I'm not referring to merging models. Here, the different data sets are user-article and user-subscription data. Both can be added in one model, with different weights. It actually doesn't matter what they are; they're defined only by weighting.

Comment: So we can have duplicit entry (same IDs) with different weight - and it is counted twice (with weight taken into account)?

Comment: Yes, these would be summed. The model is incremental / additive input. But if two things have the same ID, they are the same thing (to the model). You would not combine different types of "items" this way because different types of things would have different IDs.