# Get user neighborhood from additional data in collaborative filtering

Tags: mahout, recommendation-engine, collaborative-filtering, myrrix

I wanted to do recommendation based on multiple datasets like in [Utilizing multiple, weighed data models for a Mahout recommender](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15707013/utilizing-multiple-weighed-data-models-for-a-mahout-recommender)

But my problem is that additional data sets does not translate well into primary items. My domain is specific but imagine this as problem of recommending *movies* also based on *music* taste.

If I treat movies and music in the same manner I will get music in the results also.

I would like to use other data sets only to get better neighborhood. Is this possible with Mahout or Myrrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you treat them in the same manner, you could use the [`Rescorer`](https://builds.apache.org/job/Mahout-Quality/javadoc/org/apache/mahout/cf/taste/recommender/Rescorer.html) class to filter out the music results. Myrrix also has access to Rescorer(s)

For instance, [this `Rescorer` example](https://github.com/tdunning/MiA/blob/master/src/main/java/mia/recommender/ch05/GenreRescorer.java) from the Mahout in Action book filters out from the recommendations the books that are not in stock. You would do something similar where you would keep (somehow) track of which item ids are music and then use that information in the `Rescorer` to filter them out so they don't get recommended.

Comment: That's right. In Myrrix there is also a "CandidateFilter", which establishes which items are recommendable for any request at all (Rescorer is more per-request). You can do it either way but CandidateFilter could be faster.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't mention that, because it is labeled as experimental (for now). I also wonder if the tag api could be used for this purpose, where you would tag all the users with the music item ids, which would inform the model and won't come back out in the recommendations, what do you think?

Comment: Yes, also quite possible. The tags are automatically excluded. That works too. You would only not want to do this if you ever wanted to recommend music as well. By keeping them both as items you can do both, maybe on a per-request basis. Then you would use Rescorer indeed.